# SharePoint document library - auto numbering and renumbering

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I was wondering if you could assist me please. I have 100 documents in my document library in SharePoint.

How do I do the following?

1. Auto-number all docs automatically so that every document is numbered, 1 - 100, and then I'd like to keep adding docs to my library so the sequencing number would automatically increase.
2. Sometimes I need to delete a file from my SharePoint document library. Lets say I need to remove a document number 50. I am now left with 1-49, (50 is missing), 51 - 100. Obviously I don't want any gaps in my numbering so is it possible to re-number everything again?

I hope the above makes sense.

Thank you ever so much, I'm very new to SharePoint.

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible with the SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

Comment: Yes, as @Ganesh Sanap said, there is currently no OOTB method, not even by ID. To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to feedback on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. The more votes, the easier it is to be seen. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472